# Flyway script second flyway script after skipping first

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, flyway

Flyway seems to be skipping my V1__Create_COST_DATA.sql script, but tries to run V1.2__ALTER_COST_DATA.sql script. I'm sure I have this wrong, but this is how it looks at this point and I'm not sure why. I looked up the SQLERROR code and it basically means I'm referring to an object that doesn't exist. This is true, in my DB2INST1 schema, I to not have the COST_SSCDATA table.

This is Java Spring Boot project with a couple of DB2 databases and 3 schemas.

I'm trying to provide as much info as I can, but have changed some names for IP reasons, just to be safe.

My abbreviated stack trace:

```
...
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateSqlException: 
Migration V1.2__ALTER_COST_SPREADSHEET_Table_ADD_FILENAME.sql failed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42704
Error Code : -204
Message    : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2INST.COST_SSCDATA, DRIVER=4.19.66
Location   : db/migration/V1.2__ALTER_COST_SPREADSHEET_Table_ADD_FILENAME.sql (C:\projects-new\cirrus-spreadsheet-service\target\classes\db\migration\V1.2__ALTER_COST_SPREADSHEET_Table_ADD_FILENAME.sql)
Line       : 4
Statement  : ALTER TABLE COST_SSCDATA 
    add column FILENAME varchar(100)


    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup (DbMigrate.java:365)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$400 (DbMigrate.java:52)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.call (DbMigrate.java:297)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute (TransactionTemplate.java:75)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations (DbMigrate.java:294)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup (DbMigrate.java:259)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$300 (DbMigrate.java:52)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$4.call (DbMigrate.java:179)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$4.call (DbMigrate.java:176)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.Connection$1.call (Connection.java:155)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute (TransactionTemplate.java:75)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.Connection.lock (Connection.java:151)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock (JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:148)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll (DbMigrate.java:176)

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate (DbMigrate.java:145)

    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute (Flyway.java:1206)

    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute (Flyway.java:1168)

    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute (Flyway.java:1655)

    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate (Flyway.java:1168)

    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet (FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate (DependencyDescriptor.java:251)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject (InjectionMetadata.java:91)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)

    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:762)

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:398)

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:330)

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1258)

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1246)

    at com.mycompany.myproject.cost.spreadsheet.CostSpreadsheetUploadWebApplication.main (CostSpreadsheetUploadWebApplication.java:32)

    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)

    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)

    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)

    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2INST.COST_SSCDATA, DRIVER=4.19.66
```

V1__Create_COST_SSCDATA_Table.sql (abbreviated)

```
CREATE TABLE COST_SSCDATA
(
   SSCDATAID bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
   PROCESSGROUPID bigint,
   ...
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SQL180420024015740 ON COST_SSCDATA(SSCDATAID)
;
```

V1.2__ALTER_COST_SPREADSHEET_Table_ADD_FILENAME.sql

```
--
-- Add new field (FILENAME) to this table for storing name of the uploaded file (with extension)
--
ALTER TABLE COST_SSCDATA 
    add column FILENAME varchar(100);
```

```
flyway info
Flyway Community Edition 7.5.4 by Redgate
Database: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/bcupload (DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5)
Schema version: 1
+-----------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|           | 1       | << Flyway Baseline >>                                      | BASELINE | 2021-03-02 06:25:36 | Baseline |
| Versioned | 1.1     | Create COST SPREADSHEET Table                              | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
| Versioned | 1.2     | ALTER COST SPREADSHEET Table ADD FILENAME                  | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
| Versioned | 1.3     | Create JOB5 EXECUTION Table                                | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
| Versioned | 1.4     | Create JOB5 EXECUTION SPREADSHEET Table                    | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
| Versioned | 1.5     | Create COST SPREADSHEET BACKUP Table                       | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
| Versioned | 1.6     | ALTER COST SPREADSHEET BACKUP Table ADD STATUS REASON      | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
| Versioned | 1.7     | ALTER COST SPREADSHEET BACKUP Table UPDATE ORIG COMPANY CD | SQL      |                     | Pending  |
```

Comment: What do you get when you run flyway info? I wonder whether you've run flyway baseline against your target at V1, which means it's ignoring this script?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson Added flyway info result, sorry about the formatting.

Comment: The migrations have State Pending (not yet applied ). Look in the table you configured for the flyway history to confirm (via the 'execution_time' and 'success' columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you've set your baseline to be 1, which means that all scripts from v1 and earlier will be ignored. If you rename the migration script from V1__Create_COST_DATA.sql to V1.01__Create_COST_DATA.sql you might be alright!

Comment: I copied the line from a working version already deployed, forced the version to be NULL instead of empty or otherwise. I also saw the flyway_schema_history table had a record for the needed migration file; as though it was already done. I'm not sure how it got out of sync.  I removed the erroneous migration completion record and changed the version to NULL on the first record, plus changed it from type='BASELINE' to 'SCHEMA' then it worked. I was *trying* to clean it up with command line flyway clean, repair, etc but it never fully repaired.

Comment: On my development box, I renamed files much like you mentioned. I looked in the source code but could not find where Flyway converts the version number into an actual number, rather it looks like it treated it like a string. So to force it to use the proper order, I renamed all relevant files to be zero padded. When we deploy to test/prod, what steps need to be taken on deployment?